# Logitech G HUB script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

How can I make it so when i hold left alt and left mouse it just holds down the "L" key and then when I release left alt it goes back to the auto click script

thanks.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
        repeat
            PressKey("L")
            Sleep(math.random(15, 45)) 
            ReleaseKey("L") 
            Sleep(math.random(15, 45)) 
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      repeat
         PressKey("L")
         Sleep(math.random(15, 45)) 
         while IsModifierPressed("lalt") do
            Sleep(10)
         end
         ReleaseKey("L") 
         Sleep(math.random(15, 45)) 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```